# How did the past Thanos sense something was wrong and hence felt the need to read past Nebula's mind?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, future Nebula goes back in time to bring into effect the Avenger's plan. The minds of past and future Nebula are connected by quantum entanglement (maybe). So past Thanos gained access into future Nebula's mind via past Nebula's mind to see the future plan of the Avengers.

Now the past nebula has been living with past Thanos up till that time, all her life. After the future Nebula enters the timeline of the past Thanos, he shows up to the past Nebula saying that Ronin located an infinity stone. While saying so, he simply looks at past Nebula and feels the need to read her mind. My question is how this past Thanos sensed something is wrong and hence felt the need to read past Nebula's mind. This seems an enigma.

Answer (score 8):

He doesn't 'just decide' to read her her mind...

When 2014 (past) Nebula first hears from Thanos that he has the location of the Power Stone (Orb), she is suddenly incapacitated from the first burst of 'interference' from the 2023 (future) Nebula who has recently travelled back to 2014, resulting in her inadvertently projecting a portion of the (future) Nebula's conversation with Rhodes which is taking place simultaneously on Morag.

Despite Gamora's suggestion that the glitch was as a result of a damaged 'synaptic drive' resulting from a recent battle, Thanos decides to look more deeply into the issue, resulting in him searching back through Nebula's memories with the help of Ebony Maw

Answer (score 5):

Your memory of this scene is incorrect. Nebula has a glitch and displays a hologram of War Machine talking about Quill and how they are going to get the Power Stone. This prompts Thanos to take Nebula to his ship and read her memory. Its not as you say that he simply feels the need to read her mind.

> THANOS (2014): Ronan's located the Power Stone. I'm dispatching you to his ship.
>
> GAMORA (2014): He won't like that.
>
> THANOS (2014): His alternative is death, then. [Thanos wipes his double-bladed sword] Ronan's obsession clouds his judgement.
>
> NEBULA (2014): We will not fail you, Father.
>
> [Gamora (2014) rolls her eyes]
>
> THANOS (2014): No, you won't.
>
> NEBULA (2014): I swear...I will make you proud.
>
> **[Nebula (2014) is suddenly in pain and opens up future Nebula's memories]**
>
> **RHODEY (Memory): We just, wait around for this Quill guy to show up, and then he leads us to the Power Stone, is that it?**
>
> **NEBULA (Memory): Let's take cover. We're not the only ones in 2014 looking for the stones.**
>
> [Nebula (2014) shuts off the memory]
>
> GAMORA (2014): Who was that?
>
> NEBULA (2014): I don't know...My head is splitting...I don't know...
>
> GAMORA (2014): Her synaptic drive was probably damaged in battle.
>
> [Thanos walks towards Nebula and brings his blade to her throat]
>
> **THANOS (2014): Ssshhh... (pointing to Nebula) Bring her to my ship.**

Comment: edited my question about what thanos says.

Comment: @CuriousMind your edit doesn't change the false assumption you make that Thanos searching Nebula's memories was unprompted.

Comment: @sanpaco-I commented clearly above that I edited what I thought thanos 'said' to nebula about the infinity stone (which i know now is wrong). I did 'not' comment above that i edited my assumption that Thanos searching nebula's memories was prompted. If I edit 'that', there is 'no reason' for the question to be posted here!When i watched the movie it kind of made me think as if thanos was doing some telekinetic power to open nebula's head & read/see the events in nebula's mind. And thats why i asked this question.I now got the answer that it was unprompted.